# Make directories for each file placed in main directory

Tags: linux, bash, filenames

I want to place a list of files into individual directories I create from each filename. 
So given the files in the root directory:

```
Movie1.avi
movie2.m4v
movie3.mp4
```

I want to mkdir `Movie1`, `movie2`, and `movie3`,
then move each file into the corresponding directory.

Any simple way to to generate the directories and then move the files.

```
mkdir << find /Video/Movies/ -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort
mv << find /Video/Movies/ -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort
```

Comment: The command at the end of the question is never explicitly referenced in the question. Is it not working? Do you want a better command?

Answer (score 0):

You could define this function and use it with a wildcard...

```
movetofolder(){
for F in $@; do 
    FOLDER=${F%.*}
    mkdir "$FOLDER"
    mv "$F" "$FOLDER"
done
}
```

Usage: `movetofolder *ovie*`

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

> mkdir container && find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mkdir ./container/{} \; -exec mv {} ./container/{}/ \; -exec mv ./container/{} ./ \;  && rm -r container